# Acrobat X: How to show 0 results calculated from other calculated results?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have a calculated field in by Acrobat X form that correctly displays either an empty field (when its source field is empty) or a value *including zero* when the source field has a value. So that works correctly.

But if I try to use the result of that calculated field to then calculate another field, the last field *will not display when the calculated result is zero*. All *other* calculated values in the final field display fine, except zero.

Is there an issue with chained Acrobat calculated fields that would cause this?

Forcing visibility in a Validate script, or formatting the number in a Format script do not seem to matter. The second calculated field appears to see the first as having the value '' when it has the value zero.